# Blurry small size images

Tags: html, css, image

The image is 30px high. I downloaded the images with the lowest resolution I found and with a good quality. However, they are blurry.
I put a hover animation and when I move the mouse, in the time that the animation occurs it defaults and then becomes blurry again.
Is there any way to solve this ??

[image]

Comment: What hover animation? Do you have a minimum reproducible example?

Answer (score 0):

You could download `SVG` version of it

Comment: Yeah, I'm looking for it. The problem is I will use several images like this and I think it will be difficult to find svg of all of them. I was wondering if you have any possibility of solving this in the code using png or jpeg images

Comment: If they are blurry on low dimension you either have to find a smaller version of the picture or an svg version of it.
Usually you can find brand svg easily.